# Blender 2.83 Optix Viewport Denoising Not Enabled for Multi GPU systems?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, denoise

I'm using a multi GPU win 64 system and I was hoping to try out the new Optix viewport denoiser in the latest daily build of Blender 2.83.
In the preferences menu, Blender recognizes my CUDA capability as the following:
[image: 1 RTX 2070, 1 GTX 980 Ti, and my CPU]

However, when I switch over to the OptiX tab, it says I have no compatible GPUs for path tracing.

Unless I'm mistaken, I was fairly certain that OptiX would run on a 2070. Does OptiX not support multi-generational card builds?

Thanks!